# Expanded Notification is collapsed after 10 seconds, how to increase this value?

Tags: android, android-notifications

After I send a notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(myVarSmallIconResId)
                        .setContentTitle(myVarTitle)
                        .setContentText(myVarText);

//set bigPicture from Bitmap
Bitmap bitmap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.some_id);
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap_image);
s.setSummaryText("Summary text appears on expanding the notification");
s.setBigContentTitle("Big Content Title");

mBuilder.setStyle(s);
```

Notification appear expanded. But after 10 seconds, it contracted.

How I can to manage this time?

Comment: seems like this is default behavior of android os, and there are no legal way to edit this time.
according to https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html its only says "it is presented to users for a short period of time"